# how set the color of dates in calender in android

Tags: java, android, calendar

I am using a Calendar View in Android I want to change the color of specific dates in calendar. For instance, I might want to set the color of all holidays to green, or the color of days with meetings to red. How can I do this in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using CalenderView to create your own CustomCalendarView and change any desired colors in appearance.

You can find the code for the native CalendarView [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.1_r2/com/android/calendar/CalendarView.java).

Answer (score 0):

Use this one:

`import android.widget.CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener;`